# What are the possible manual test cases for captcha

Tags: manual-testing, functional

There is registration page we have introduced captcha to, and we need to test it manually - what are the possible test cases for captcha?

Comment: Have you implemented `CAPTCHA`, `reCAPTCHA` or `No CAPTCHA reCAPTCHA`?

Comment: reCAPTCHA we have implemented

Comment: What is the difference between captcha and reCAPTCHA

Comment: [This thread from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130334/difference-between-captcha-and-recaptcha) asks exactly that, so might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

1. CAPTCHA is present on the page.
2. CAPTCHA field should be required for every login action.
3. CAPTCHA code should not be repeated.
4. CAPTCHA should not be copyable by mouse/selection.
5. CAPTCHA should be changed if the page is refreshed.
6. New CAPTCHA should be generated if the wrong CAPTCHA was entered by user.
7. CAPTCHA can be case sensitive (According to requirement).
8. CAPTCHA should be readable/visible by human.
9. CAPTCHA should be displayed completely. Not cut by sides.
10. User's IP should be blocked by website if incorrect captcha submission attempts is reached.

Comment: Regarding the 10th point, would that not be testing the website instead of Google Captcha? Google Captcha isn't able to block IP addresses on the sites behalf.

Comment: 11: Look for the name of the CAPTCHA image on the machine. Ensure the name is *not* the CAPTCHA code.
12: Enter blank response, incorrect response, correct response, a billion characters in the response, HTML, javascript. Correct response should allow access, the rest should not, and should not show a TMI error.

Answer (score 0):

Validate user is presented with ReCAPTCHA

Validate user cannot skip ReCAPTCHA

Validate user can successfully finish ReCAPTCHA

Validate user failed ReCAPTCHA will increment fail counter by 1.

Validate user is presented with Verify ReCAPTCHA (when the first captcha is correct but it needs to be verified further).

Your tests need to be clear that you are not testing ReCaptcha, you are testing the integration with ReCaptcha

Just a couple, but you need to validate success, presentation of the captcha and failed attempts.

Answer (score 0):

There can be various test cases which can be followed in functional testing services. Below are some of the important ones:

1. Validate that the system accepts valid Captcha.
2. Validate  that the system rejects the invalid Captcha.
3. Validate  that the Captcha code resets as the system reloads.
4. Validate  that the Captcha changes as the user enters wrong value.
5. Validate  the readability of the Captcha.
6. Validate  that the user receives new captcha on clicking the link.
7. Validate  that the user receives information about how to use the captcha, on clicking the help button.
8. Validate that the audio version of Captcha is working